# Transform vector from xy plane to "another vector's plane"

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

[image]

I've not had linear algebra yet, so bear with me if I write something weird. Given vector A and B as shown above, how do I transform vector B so that one of its components is parallel to A, and the other perpendicular?

The application is as follows: Vector A represents the direction of an object, vector B represents an acceleration. I want to find out the acceleration that points in the object's direction, (its tangential acceleration), and the acceleration pointing perpendicular to the object (radial acceleration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hint:

Use the dot product between two vectors to get the parallel components by using the following formula
$$\overrightarrow{B}.\frac{\overrightarrow{A}}{|A|}$$

For perpendicular component, you can get another vector perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{A}$ and use the same fromula.

Comment: Thanks! But won't that formula always end up with a positive number?

Comment: @lawls I have edited the formula

Comment: Would you mind elaborating how I find the perpendicular component? I'm able to find the parallel component using the formula you wrote, but I'm not sure how I would get the perpendicular component. I could find a perpendicular vector to A, but what magnitude should it have for the formula to work?

Comment: @lawls For example (for vector in plane only) : if you have a vector in plane $$\overrightarrow{A}=v_1i+v_2j$$. The perpendicular vector to the $\overrightarrow{A}$ is $$\overrightarrow{P}=v_1i-v_2j$$ or $$\overrightarrow{P}=-v_1i+v_2j$$

Comment: Thank you, seems to be working perfectly!

Comment: @lawls you're welcome